# What is the difference between "pli" and "plu"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between *pli* and *plu*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From Vortaro:

**Pli**
*Partikulo, esprimanta kvanton aŭ gradon superan al unu alia.*
A particle, showing quantity or degree above another.

Examples:

- Milk is more nutritious than wine. 
   
  *lakto estas pli nutra, ol vino*
- We can do nothing more than
  be silent. 
   
  *ni povas fari nenion pli, ol silenti*
- Around ten people are staying, not more. 
  *restas ĉirkaŭ dek personoj, ne pli*

**Plu**  
*Cirkonstanca morfemo, montranta la daŭradon k neĉeson de stato aŭ ago.* 
Cirumstantial morpheme, showing the duration and non-cessation of a state or action.

Examples:

- She wanted to say something more, but could not. 
   
  *ŝi volis diri ion plu, sed ŝi ne povis*
- I can not go one step more. 
   
  *mi ne povas iri unu paŝon plu*
- Don't speak (any)more. 
  *ne parolu plu*

Answer (score 8):

- *pli* is more general "more".
- *plu* is only for a time duration "longer"

*Li ne dormas plu.* = He does not sleep anymore / He no longer sleeps

Answer (score 6):

They both mean "more" but in different senses. Pli is used when you would use the -er suffix in English as in bigger, stronger, faster - pli granda, pli forta, pli rapida.

Plu is used as a stand alone as in I can't eat any more, I don't go to school any more, I no more like cheese - mi ne povas manĝi plu, mi ne plu iras al lernejo, mi ne plu ŝatas fromagon.

Answer (score 2):

I was doing a search on this question and I found an interesting blog that does a good job explaining, too.

The blog is called [Adventures in Esperanto](https://adventuresinesperanto.wordpress.com/tag/plu/#:%7E:text=).  Here is some of what it says about the subject:

> **Pli versus Plu!**
>
> Abstractly, the difference is this: “plu” is “further/additionally/more” in relation to time or space. “Pli” means “more” but in relation to size, grade or degree.
>
> So while “plu” is used for something that is continuing or ongoing, “pli” means “more than a certain amount” and as such is used for comparisons.
>
> - La melo ne plu aŭskultas al mi = The badger no longer [/more] listens to me
> - La melo estas pli bela ol la kato = The badger is more beautiful than the cat.
>
> This shows that obviously if you use “ne” in conjunction with “plu” is means to not continue etc.
>
> Something a little harder? I found this example on the PMEG page about “plu” using the word “rakonti” = “to relate/tell/narrate”
>
> - Li rakontis plu = He continued his narration (narrated more)
> - Li rakontis pli = He related more things (than previously/up until now/than others do/did)

I know this question has been answered, but thought I would share this as another resource.